# Typhoon - additional collaborating assemblies activation

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, dependency-injection, typhoon

Is it possible to activate additional assemblies on the fly?

For example, in `Info.plist` I have two assemblies: `UIAssembly` and `ServicesComponents`.

Besides these, I have multiple storyboards, each one with its own assembly. I don't want to load all of them at the start-up, because most of objects will be unused.

So, after `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method, the startUpRouter goes into play - it should create the TyphoonStoryboard with the TyphoonComponentFactory, that includes both initial assemblies and new UserStoryAssembly.

Answer (score 2):

It is certainly possible to create additional assemblies besides the one that is bound to your app using [plist integration](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/Plist-Integration), however you should not need to do this.

[Activating assemblies](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/Activating-Assemblies) does not instantiate any new objects. What happens is that, using assemblies, we create a registry of recipes for instantiating new objects. . .

*(Typhoon uses run-time instrumentation to assign unique keys to each definition, based on the definition's method name. This allows IDE code completion, refactoring, etc without building any special tool support).*

. . . this information consumes little memory and is stored in the `TyphoonComponentFactory` class. What happens is that after activation, the `TyphoonAssembly` will use objective-C message forwarding to send messages to the factory, which will only then assemble an instance according to the defined [scope rules](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/Scopes). The default scope is ObjectGraph which allows defining a network of relationships for a use-case and then discarding this when done. *(This is a unique feature for applying dependency injection to mobile and desktop software).* Only singleton scoped objects are retained.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was worrying abuot storing explicit objects in memory, while the application doesn't need them.